# How to merge two groupingBy in java streams?

Tags: java, hashmap, java-stream, collectors

I have a input object

```
  @Getter
  class Txn {

    private String hash;
    private String withdrawId;
    private String depositId;
    private Integer amount;
    private String date;

  }
```

and the output object is

```
  @Builder
  @Getter
  class UserTxn {

    private String hash;
    private String walletId;
    private String txnType;
    private Integer amount;
  }
```

In the **Txn** object transfers the **amount** from the **withdrawId -> depositId**.

what I am doing is I am **adding** all the **transactions** (Txn objects) in a single amount **grouped by hash**.

but for that I have to make **two streams for groupingby** withdrawId and second or for depositId and then the **third stream for merging** them

grouping by withdrawId

```
var withdrawStream = txnList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Txn::getHash, LinkedHashMap::new,
        Collectors.groupingBy(Txn::getWithdrawId, LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.toList())))
    .entrySet().stream().flatMap(hashEntrySet -> hashEntrySet.getValue().entrySet().stream()
        .map(withdrawEntrySet ->
            UserTxn.builder()
                .hash(hashEntrySet.getKey())
                .walletId(withdrawEntrySet.getKey())
                .txnType("WITHDRAW")
                .amount(withdrawEntrySet.getValue().stream().map(Txn::getAmount).reduce(0, Integer::sum))
                .build()
        ));
```

grouping by depositId

```
var depositStream = txnList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Txn::getHash, LinkedHashMap::new,
        Collectors.groupingBy(Txn::getDepositId, LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.toList())))
    .entrySet().stream().flatMap(hashEntrySet -> hashEntrySet.getValue().entrySet().stream()
        .map(withdrawEntrySet ->
            UserTxn.builder()
                .hash(hashEntrySet.getKey())
                .walletId(withdrawEntrySet.getKey())
                .txnType("DEPOSIT")
                .amount(withdrawEntrySet.getValue().stream().map(Txn::getAmount).reduce(0, Integer::sum))
                .build()
        ));
```

then merging them again, using deposites - withdraws

```
var res = Stream.concat(withdrawStream, depositStream).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(UserTxn::getHash, LinkedHashMap::new,
    Collectors.groupingBy(UserTxn::getWalletId, LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.toList())))
    .entrySet().stream().flatMap(hashEntrySet -> hashEntrySet.getValue().entrySet().stream()
        .map(withdrawEntrySet -> {
              var depositAmount = withdrawEntrySet.getValue().stream().filter(userTxn -> userTxn.txnType.equals("DEPOSIT")).map(UserTxn::getAmount).reduce(0, Integer::sum);
              var withdrawAmount = withdrawEntrySet.getValue().stream().filter(userTxn -> userTxn.txnType.equals("WITHDRAW")).map(UserTxn::getAmount).reduce(0, Integer::sum);
              var totalAmount = depositAmount-withdrawAmount;
              return UserTxn.builder()
                  .hash(hashEntrySet.getKey())
                  .walletId(withdrawEntrySet.getKey())
                  .txnType(totalAmount > 0 ? "DEPOSIT": "WITHDRAW")
                  .amount(totalAmount)
                  .build();
            }
        ));
```

My question is, How can I do this in one stream.
Like by somehow groupingBy withdrawId and depositId is one grouping.

something like

```
res = txnList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Txn::getHash,
            LinkedHashMap::new,
            Collectors.groupingBy(Txn::getWithdrawId && Txn::getDepositId,
                LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.toList())))
        .entrySet().stream().flatMap(hashEntrySet -> hashEntrySet.getValue().entrySet().stream()
            .map(walletEntrySet ->
                {
                  var totalAmount = walletEntrySet.getValue().stream().map(
                      txn -> Objects.equals(txn.getDepositId(), walletEntrySet.getKey())
                          ? txn.getAmount() : (-txn.getAmount())).reduce(0, Integer::sum);
                  return UserTxn.builder()
                      .hash(hashEntrySet.getKey())
                      .walletId(walletEntrySet.getKey())
                      .txnType("WITHDRAW")
                      .amount(totalAmount)
                      .build();
                }
            ));
```

Comment: How about creating a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I have added a minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### TL;DR

For those who didn't understand the question, OP wants to generate from each `Txn` instance (`Txn` probably stands for transaction) **two** peaces of data: `hash` and `withdrawId` + aggregated amount, and `hash` and `depositId` + aggregated amount.

And then they want to merge the two parts together (for that reason they were creating the two streams, and then concatenating them).

***Note:** it seems like there's a logical flow in the original code: the same amount gets associated with `withdrawId` and `depositId`. Which doesn't reflect that this amount has been taken from one account and transferred to another. Hence, it would make sense if for `depositId` amount would be used as is, and for `withdrawId` - negated (i.e. `-1 * amount`).*

## [`Collectors.teeing()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#teeing(java.util.stream.Collector,java.util.stream.Collector,java.util.function.BiFunction))

You can make use of the Java 12 Collector `teeing()` and internally group stream elements into two distinct Maps:

- the first one by grouping the stream data by `withdrawId` and `hash`.
- and another one by grouping the data `depositId` and `hash`.

Teeing expects three arguments: 2 downstream Collectors and a Function combining the results produced by collectors.

As the downstream of `teeing()` we can use a combination of Collectors `groupingBy()` and [`summingInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#summingInt(java.util.function.ToIntFunction)), the second one is needed to accumulate integer `amount` of the transaction.

**Note** that there's no need in using nested Collector `groupingBy()` instead we can create a custom type that would hold `id` and `hash` (*and its `equals/hashCode` should be implemented based on the wrapped id and hash*). [Java 16 `record`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/language/records.html) fits into this role perfectly well:

```
public record HashWalletId(String hash, String walletId) {}
```

Instances of `HashWalletId` would be used as Keys in both intermediate Maps.

The *finisher function* of `teeing()` would merge the results of the two Maps together.

The only thing left is to generate instances of `UserTxn` out of map entries.

```
List<Txn> txnList = // initializing the list
        
List<UserTxn> result = txnList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.teeing(
        Collectors.groupingBy(
            txn -> new HashWalletId(txn.getHash(), txn.getWithdrawId()),
            Collectors.summingInt(txn -> -1 * txn.getAmount())), // because amount has been withdrawn
        Collectors.groupingBy(
            txn -> new HashWalletId(txn.getHash(), txn.getDepositId()),
            Collectors.summingInt(Txn::getAmount)),
        (map1, map2) -> {
            map2.forEach((k, v) -> map1.merge(k, v, Integer::sum));
            return map1;
        }
    ))
    .entrySet().stream()
    .map(entry -> UserTxn.builder()
        .hash(entry.getKey().hash())
        .walletId(entry.getKey().walletId())
        .txnType(entry.getValue() > 0 ? "DEPOSIT" : "WITHDRAW")
        .amount(entry.getValue())
        .build()
    )
    .toList(); // remove the terminal operation if your goal is to produce a Stream
```

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn’t use this in my code because I think it’s not readable and will be very hard to change and manage in the future(SOLID).
But in case you still want this-

If I got your design right hash is unique per user and transaction will only have deposit or withdrawal, if so, this will work-

You could triple groupBy via collectors chaining like you did in your example.
You can create the `Txn` type via simple map function just check which id is null.

```
Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, List<Txn>>>> groupBy = 
      txnList.stream()
             .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Txn::getHash, LinkedHashMap::new,
                       Collectors.groupingBy(Txn::getDepositId, LinkedHashMap::new,
                         Collectors.groupingBy(Txn::getWithdrawId, LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.toList()))));
```

then use the logic from your example on this stream.